# How do I change the look of appointments in Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, calendar

In Outlook 2013, when in the calendar, I can have the subject of the appointments either aligned to the right or to the left, using the ltr/rtl settings. Is there a way to not use those settings, and center the subject of the appointments? Just like multiple day appointments appear centered on each day in their duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are not ways to do that, sorry. You can try to prefix subjects with spaces but I don't think this is what you want to do.

Comment: Well, that answers my question. Not the answer I wanted, but what can one do.